# Is it possible to have an "Inkognito" user?

Tags: restore, user-management, lock

I would like to be able to have a user where the following are true:

1. The user is a "normal" user, i.e. non-superuser
2. After a user logs out, the system "restores" the system

   - If anything was deleted, undo that action
   - The order of the shortcuts on the desktop should be the same
   - The browser history/cache should be deleted
   - Basically, it should be have as "DeepFreeze" for Windows XP
3. The user should not be allowed to change internet connection settings, i.e. DNS server
4. The clock should auto-change from summer to winter time and visa versa
5. Most importantly, the system should be allowed to auto-update security packages and keep that persistent

I have tried `OFRIS`, but this does not keep updates persistent without using `sudo` to unfreeze and does not allow clock changes.
It seems like `Lethe` have the exact same issues, since it only keep changes in RAM at all time.

I am going to install this in 200+ computers, so having to manually update via `sudo` or change the clock would be way too time consuming.

Comment: Why the guest user doesn't work for you? It is created on the spot, without privileges, and it is immediately deleted on logout.

Comment: @Rmano As far as I know it is not a complete solution for the problem because there you cannot restrict the access to any of the settings.

Comment: @ArmandBozsik are right. I didn't specify it above, but there should also be some preinstalled programs with shortcuts on the Desktop. Even with the `CustomizeGuestSession`, it does not seem to be possible to do that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create a new user with the equivalent of a Windows guest-user's permissions?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/7994/how-can-i-create-a-new-user-with-the-equivalent-of-a-windows-guest-users-permis)

Answer (score 1):

"I am going to install this in 200+ computers, so having to manually update via sudo or change the clock would be way too time consuming."

Not the answer to the question but I believe there is a better method for what you are asking. There is a piece of software called [puppet](https://puppetlabs.com/puppet/what-is-puppet) where you have a "master" and an unknown amount of "puppets" where the master controls the puppets.

All the demands you list (and lots more you and I never ever thought about) can be done by setting up a master and instructing it to update the puppets.

This not only makes it possible for you to create a restricted account with more permissions than just a generic guest account but any maintenance you need to do is made a lot easier.

- [debian/ubuntu install](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/3.8/reference/install_debian_ubuntu.html) for puppet.
- [Getting started with Puppet Enterprise](http://www.swoops.co.uk/howto-build-puppet-enterprise-lab/) from swoop.co.uk